# Исключение типов

Tags: typescript

Есть ли в ts возможность указать тип "объект, но не массив", так, чтобы в строке (2) показывало ошибку?

```
type Box = {};

function test(a: Box): any {

}

test({}); // (1)
test([]); // (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На пустой объект `{}` `ts` не ругается, но если добавить в него любое свойтство, то сразу ругаться [начинает](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&pretty=true&ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDygXigbwLACgq6gQwC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG5sBfRrbAMzJIGNgBLOCSjAIAZ2AAKIrEQBKYvhIh02PFG6DRcADYQAdNrgBzKbNZNs2EeIloiARiZmoAehdQJ92VbGSA2gC6zm4eAEyyQA):

```
type Box = {
    a: number;
};

function test(a: Box): any {
    console.log(a);
}

test({a:1}); // (1)
test([]); // (2)
```